# Add routes to Bluemix PAAS Instance without Downtime

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, delivery-pipeline, active-deploy

I have created a Bluemix application and I have also configured the Delivery pipeline in such a way it does the zero downtime deployment with the help of active deploy but in order to add more routes to the instance I need to use either the CF CLI or Bluemix Console which will make the application to restart or restage.

I have also tried adding the routes to the manifest.yml file which is not helping as the Active Deploy based deployment in Delivery Pipeline did not consider the routes added to the manifest file at all.

I would like to add a route to the application based on the requirements without any downtime to the application. Any suggestions or way to handle this?

Comment: This might be of help to you "Using Blue-Green Deployment to Reduce Downtime and Risk" http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

Comment: Here is information about Blue-Green deployments from the Bluemix documentation: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#blue_green

Comment: I have used Blue Green Deployment already but the issue with blue green deployment is that you cannot gradually reduce the traffic being sent to the new instance instead just send all traffic to new instance.